# How to open home page from visualforce page in console?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, console

[image]

If you looked into the above image. Here **Pick Your Branch** is a visualforce tab. In this VF page one button is there called **Save**.

On Click of Save, I need to close the VF page and Open  home page.

I am able to open the Home page using

```
window.location='/home/home.jsp?isdtp=vw';
```

But if you see **Pick Your Branch** tab name and icon will remain same

[image]

I tried to set the title and icon using below code but since it is redirecting to another page it is not able to set the title and icon.

```
sforce.console.setTabTitle('Home');
sforce.console.setTabIcon('/img/icon/t4v35/standard/home_60.png', null, checkResult);
```

I am looking for any standard way to open home tab in console and close my current VF page tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research I found that, We can open tab using `setSelectedNavigationTab()`

Documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_setselectednavigatortab.htm

Using below code I am able to open home page. **'nav-tab-1'**  is the home tab Id.

```
 sforce.console.setSelectedNavigationTab(callback,'nav-tab-1');

 var callback = function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
              console.log('Successful');
            } else {
              console.log('something is wrong!');
            }
        }
```